# What are direct experimental evidences that quarks exist?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, standard-model, quarks, partons

Now we have very established model of quarks explaining fundamental strong interaction. What are experimental proofs for existence of quarks and what is the name of physicist which made them?

Comment: Another history question. ;) [Beginning in 1967, SLAC carried out the "deep inelastic" electron-proton scattering experiments that revealed the structure of the proton as a bound state of quarks.](https://www.aps.org/programs/outreach/history/historicsites/slac.cfm)

Comment: Maybe, something more direct? Interpreting of scattering depends on the model...

Comment: Fair point, but remember that observation of isolated quarks is impossible, due to color confinement.

Comment: No other models explain the scattering results as simply and as well as the quark model does.

Comment: No. Just trying to check the basis of quark model. The early basis is statement that neutron is the same type of particles as proton. The current basis direct experimenal proofs for quarks. But asking about neutron is really better in the history branch, thanks )

Comment: Ohhh. It is difficult to stop asking ) As it interesting if any direct experimental proofs for possibility of particles with confinment to exist )

Comment: G. Smith, which one models were tested to compare?

Comment: @coodan The main pre-quark model that I’m aware of was the “parton” model. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parton_(particle_physics) At some point it became obvious that the partons were in fact quarks. If you believe that the scientific process works, as I do, then you don’t have to worry that better models are somehow ignored and suppressed. That would represent a massive failure of science. So I have never had any interest in non-quark models.

Comment: Put differently, I have no reason to believe that the Standard Model, with adjustments for massive neutrinos, is not *currently* the best model we have for particle physics. It is almost certainly wrong at some level, but it is the best we have *now*. I believe in mainstream physics, not fringe theories.

Comment: I agree, that Standart Model is very beatiful, have strong symmetry approach and give very good result. But the statement was that it is the theory which is the best in explaining of scattering results. To be best is to be compared to other. Which models were compared on scattering?

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/228898/what-evidence-is-there-of-the-existence-of-quarks), [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/201990/can-quarks-be-considered-real-and-elementary), and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/60356/how-quark-electric-charge-directly-have-been-measured) for discussions of this question. Also, the [wikipedia article on Deep inelastic scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_inelastic_scattering).

Comment: Probably, some direct proofs do exist?

Comment: @coodan - what do you mean by 'direct proof'? Are the experiments not sufficient?

Comment: if by direct evidence you mean, "has anybody ever seen an isolated quark" the answer is no. from what I understand, most physicists believe this can never be achieved, due to what is called color confinement. the basic idea runs as follows: quarks are bound to one another by what is known as a strong force, and at a certain point during the separation of two charges bound by this force it becomes energetically favorable to form a new quark/anti-quark pair (a process known as hadronization)

Comment: Yes. That is a matter of belief :)

Comment: I would like to say thanks to PM 2ring for redirection to Science Hystory branch in previous question and to Qmechanic for redirection to same question here, as it was special pleasure to find and to read answers of anna v, as her style and understanding of Physics cause my deepest respect.

Comment: Not. Experiments is not suffiscent if they are not direct.

Comment: Any other particles, which would have such a behavior is experimentally proven? Usually, in physics, interaction fall with the distance. Why to increase?

Comment: @coodan Briefly, that happens because gluons, the mediators of the strong force, have color charge. There are existing questions here on this topic, but you can also read about it on the site of Frank Wilczek, who won the Nobel prize for his work in QCD. See http://www.frankwilczek.com/core.html

Comment: Thank you very much for the link. I am new here and should learn how to use interface. It is very interesting to read opinion from the author of concept. May be you know also why crached the proton-neutron model and ideas of protons and neutrons, interacting via generation of neutral pion was exchanged for quarks, interacting directly via gluons? As it is a middle of the basis...